# How to run javascript outside of router function in Foxx

Tags: arangodb

I would like to do some variable toggling for dev and prod production but it seemed like If..else does not run outside of router code. Am I doing something wrong?

```
//Other variable declare above
//This one wont run
if(isDev){
coll=db._collection("DevColl")
}
else{
coll=db._collection("ProdColl");
}
//////////////////////////////////
//Later use coll in the router code
router.get("/"),function{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that ArangoDB starts several Javascript V8 contexts (they call this "Isolate") while NodeJS just has one.

During the lifecycle of ArangoDB new Isolates may be spawned, and old ones flushed. Global objects in Isolates that are not being referenced may be removed to save memory.

Thus there is no direct way to have global setting inside of javascript.

However, there are three possible ways to achieve this:

- A collection that can switch the state (may be slow in production too...)
- using the system environment via [`process.env`](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.4/Manual/Appendix/JavaScriptModules/) which you then would have to set in the initscripts starting ArangoDB.
- install another instance of your foxx service, access the collections via [`module.context.collection()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47976621/why-in-arangodb-module-context-collection-return-null)