# Why in ArangoDB module.context.collection return null

Tags: arangodb, foxx

I'm trying to learn how to develop Foxx services.

There are many examples where people use:

```
const someCollection = module.context.collection('someCollectionName');
```

But in my project this code doesn't work.
someCollection always null, but it's exist in collections.

And this code works perfectly:

```
const db = require('@arangodb').db;
const someCollection = db._collection('someCollectionName');
```

My question is why first code isn't work?

Comment: Please provide more context in accordance with the guidelines (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Have you followed the guidance at https://docs.arangodb.com/3.3/Manual/Foxx/Context.html ? What is your "require" statement?

Answer (score 0):

Foxx services are intended to have their own collections, and being able to be installeable multiple times.

Thus `module.context.collection('someCollectionName');` will give you a collection prefixed with the mountpoint of your Foxx-Service, wheres `db._collection('someCollectionName');` will always give you the same collection name regardles of which installation of this foxx services you are in - thus several installations may interfere each other.

The easiest way to get started with a complete example that has collections and simple code stubs for manipulation is to choose this clickpath in the UI:

`Services` -> `Add Service`=> `New`

And fill

`'someCollectionName'` into `Document Collections:`